# C#: Is there a way to determine if we are currently in deserialization mode from within a property set?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I don't want to calculate positions or throw an exception because the values are checked and set interdependently (*inter-* ***NOT*** *ind-*) of one another.  If the value was serialized, I know it is a valid value, so I want to bypass the `CalcNewPositions` call if it's during deserialization.  Is there a way to know if we are currently in deserialization mode?  Otherwise I will get the exception thrown since one of the values isn't set yet.  (When initialized outside of serialization, we init with two valid values for `_x` and `_y`.)

```
[DataContract]
Class Foo{
    ...
    [DataMember]
    public double X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            // I WANT TO BYPASS THIS IF WE'RE MID-DESERIALIZATION
            if (!CalcNewPositions(value, _y))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(value + " Out of Bounds: ");
            }

            _x = value;
            _lastGoodX = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public double Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            // I WANT TO BYPASS THIS IF WE'RE MID-DESERIALIZATION
            if (!CalcNewPositions(_x, value))
            {

                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(value + " Out of Bounds: ");
            }

            _y = value;
            _lastGoodY = value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

As I did more research my first thought was to try to use `ISerializable` to set a field I could later check in the setters for X and Y:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
Class Foo : ISerializable {
    ...
    protected Foo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        _deserializing = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

But I got the exception `Type 'Foo' cannot be ISerializable and have DataContractAttribute attribute`.  Since the project currently uses DataContract everywhere, I don't think I can go that route.

Comment: If `y` validates only when `x` is set and vice versa, how do either of them ever get set via properties?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp as mentioned, "we init with two valid values for _x and _y"

Comment: When a serializer creates ("inits") the object during serialization, arent those internal values also set then?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp The values could be initialized at deserialization time, but the call to do so requires significant processing that I don't want to do at deserialization time because it could slow down the loading of the file.

Comment: Did you check the serialization callback functions OnSerializing and OnDeserializing? More [info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/09/05/wcf-extensibility-serialization-callbacks/)

Comment: @Thangadurai I was composing my answer when you commented. :) Thanks for responding though!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnDeserializing()` and `OnDeserialized()` attributes.  In the class do this:

```
private bool _deserializing;

[OnDeserializing()]
internal void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
{
    _deserializing = true;
}

[OnDeserialized()]
internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    // do validations of the values here once they're both set

    _deserializing = false;
}

public double X
{
    get { return _x; }
    set
    {
        if (!_deserializing)
        {
            if (!CalcNewPositions(value, _y))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(value + " Out of Bounds: ");
            }
        }

        _x = value;
        _lastGoodX = value;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: You'll want to clear the flag and check the object's overall validity in an `[OnDeserialized]` event.

Comment: @dbc I checked during deserialization and the flag was set to false when entering `OnDeserializing` as each instance was deserialized, I believe demonstrating I don't need to do the first part.  But am I not understanding something (it's very possible as I'm pretty new to serialization) about deserialization that would warrant clearing the flag as you suggest in `OnDeserialized`?

Comment: `_deserializing` should be `true` only during deserialization, right?  So you need to set it to false when deserialization is complete.  This can most appropriately be done in an `[OnDeserialized]` event.

Comment: @dbc Sorry, I wasn't thinking very straight yesterday.  You are correct.  Thank you!  I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Another option would be to eliminate the `_deserializing` member and `OnDeserializing` method, put `[DataMember(Name = XXX)]` on the underlying private fields `_x` and `_y` rather than the properties, and do all the validations and postprocessing in `OnDeserialized`.